# Why can't I change my username?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I went on Minecraft.net to reset my username because I bought the game and it didn't let me sign in, so I went to reset it, but it says that my email isn't on record! What does that mean and how can I reset my username so I can get all of the new updates? Since I can't sign in, I'm stuck on version 1.4.6! I don't have any horses or other cool stuff! Help!

Comment: [Contact Mojang Support](http://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new) -- we can do nothing for you.

Comment: Have you tried going to mojang.com to reset your account password? As far as I know, they don't use minecraft.net to handle account stuff anymore.

Answer (score 3):

All I can do is suggest you migrate your Minecraft account to a Mojang one. To do this, go to https://account.mojang.com/migrate and type in your Minecraft username and password.

Comment: Please include the relevant steps.  Saves people a click.

Comment: Really, no need. You have to click to do it anyway, and there's really not much to do. EDIT: Added the two steps.